# In Javascript how to make arrays with custom behavior that can be instantiated?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I need an kind of "circular array". I have everything working but for single instance. I don't know how to make it "instantiable". I mean I want it to work the following way:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; // it's kind of pseudo-code 
arr.getNext(); // gives a
arr.getNext(); // gives b
arr.getNext(); // gives c
arr.getNext(); // gives d
arr.getNext(); // gives a
arr.getNext(); // gives b
// and so on
```

I know I can create object with array inside and iterate over it, but I'm pretty sure I can do this the other way.

The problem is I need several instances of that object. If it was only one instance I could do:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
arr.getNext = function() {
  // ... I got this stuff working
}
```

How to allow createion of several instances of such custom arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you can extend `Array.prototype` with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) (to create a non-enumerable property), an alternative solution might be interesting as well, depending on your actual needs.

You could define a function that returns an *iterator* over an array:

```
function iter(arr) {
    var index = -1;

    return {
        next: function() {
            index = (index + 1) % arr.length;
            return arr[index];
        }
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
var it = iter(arr);
it.next();
```

Comment: Oh, thats pretty cool. I haven't thought about this that way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `prototype` to be able to use it in all instances of `Array`:

```
Array.prototype.getNext = function(){
  var next = this.shift();
  this.push(next);
  return next;
};
```

Note that this modifies the array.

Comment: A small point/question: Do you need to extend the Array prototype? How would Array.getNext = function() { ... } differ?

Comment: Yes, if you do it like this you _need_ to extend the prototype. `Array.getNext` attaches an object to the global `Array` object, not to each instance, so the context of `this` would be lost. But you can always create your own function and pass in an array like `function getNext(arr){...}`

Comment: Oh of course, coincidentally I was looking at a piece of code that did a similar `Object.func = ...`, and wondered how this was different but then realised that it wasn't meant to be added to all object instances.

Comment: I don't want if for all arrays, that's why I don't want to extend Array.prototype and here is where my problem begins :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add you getNext method to the Array prototype, like this:

```
Array.prototype.getNext = function ()
{
....
}
```

You can then call this method on any array that you create.

Comment: I don't want it to be in all my Array objects unfortunately. That's where I have problem with how to write it.

Comment: @grafthez what's the problem of having this function in all your array objects? declaring this function in the prototype does not cause any change to the behavior of arrays. You only get the additional function which you can use.

Comment: @ShaiAharoni Adding things to Object.prototype or Array.prototype changes for(things in myArray) as the function getNext would show up here. This could break someone's code that tries to use your code. Even though it's not a good idea to do for(things in array) it doesn't stop other people from trying to do so. Felix addressed this problem by mentioning Object.defineProperty (setting enumerable to false) but in my opinion this particular problem would be better solved by the iter function mentioned in his answer.